# how to add self-signed certificates in kubuntu 22?

Tags: linux, ssl, kde

So our company uses MITM to spy on us, and I need to add their ca certificates into system so that I can for example update the linux system. These are in pem form and if I do:

```
sudo cp cert1.cer cert2.cer /usr/share/ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

it will say, that it added zero certificates (yes, path is valid, files were actually copied there). If I check content of ca-certificates.crt, they are indeed not there.

I tried to add them using kde ssl preferences settings also. They are rendered as added, yet it does not work. I tried to dump these files directly into /etc/ssl/certs, does not work either. How can I add them, so that system knows about them?

note: certs are probably valid, I was able to add them into browser, intellij idea and JDK and they works there.

EDIT: originally I tested only path /usr/share/ca-certificates, which also existed in system, but certificates wasn't picked from it. Path /usr/local/share/ca-certificates worked.

Comment: KDE is a desktop environment. It is not concerned with PKI certificates. Which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: well it has some tool window in settings regarding ssl, which allows import cert. ~ sorry for title, will update, it's kubuntu 22. ~ there is both /usr/share/ca-certificates and /usr/local/share/ca-certificates. I tried the latter and this one finally worked. So I managed to find solution meanwhile. Will update the question.

Comment: @MartinMucha - instead of updating the question, add it as an answer. It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question if you find a solution as it still helps others.

Comment: try changing from .cer to .crt